# Hashbangs and UTM parameters

Tags: parameters, utm

I am trying to run some campaigns to garner registrations and would like to use UTM parameters. Problem is my website urls contain hashbangs in it. Can i still generate UTM parameters tag for my urls with hashbangs in it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can still generate UTM tags, but make sure that any URL builder puts the hash tags towards the end, i.e. after the UTM parameters are added. Otherwise there's a risk that the hash bang won't work as you intended. Not all URL builders do it correctly, but Google URL builder does create correct URLs.

e.g. After adding UTM parameters to

*www.example.com/#top*

it should be

*www.example.com/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=launch#top*

You could also try [Terminus](http://term.li/1pkmEjI) which implements it correctly. *(Disclaimer: I'm the founder and Terminus is a paid service.)*

Answer (score 0):

The safest solution might be to encode the character, using functions like encodeURIComponent() in Javascript, or similar in other languages.